# Help simplifying this Regular Expression pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have this Regular Expression that matches the following strings:

```
<!-- 09-02-2009 --->
<!-- 09-02-2009 12:00:00 --->
<!-- 09-02-2009 12:00:00 A --->
<!-- 09-02-2009 12:00:00 AM --->
```

Here is the pattern:

```
<!-- (?<month>\d{2}?)-(?<day>\d{2}?)-(?<year>\d{4}?)(?:(?: ?\d{2}:?){3}?(?: ?[aApP][mM]?)?)? --->
```

**updated pattern, per twistol:**

```
<!-- (?<month>\d{2}?)-(?<day>\d{2}?)-(?<year>\d{4}?)(?<time>(?: ?(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2})?(?: ?[aApP][mM]?)?)? --->
```

Is there anything I can do to simplify this pattern?

Thanks!

## **EDIT**

Here is the pattern I came up with all comments/answers, plus validation built in. It is a bit ugly, but who said regex needs to be pretty? :P

```
<!-- (?<month>(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]))-(?<day>(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]))-(?<year>\d{4})(?<time> (?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?: [aApP][mM]?)?)? --->
```

It will match valid dates in the following formats:

```
<!-- 09-02-2009 --->
<!-- 09-02-2009 12:00 --->
<!-- 09-02-2009 12:00 A --->
<!-- 09-02-2009 12:00 AM --->
<!-- 09-02-2009 12:00:00 --->
<!-- 09-02-2009 12:00:00 A --->
<!-- 09-02-2009 12:00:00 AM --->
```

Comment: That depends on what flavour of regex you're using. Perl, JS, etc.

Comment: can't say I can help simplify it, but wouldn't this bit also match "11:11:11:" (note the extra :)? `(?: ?\d{2}:?){3}?`

Comment: Sorry I did not specify, I am using this in a C# project.

Comment: @twistol - Yes it seems you are correct. I should probably expand that section so it does not match that string.

Comment: It'll also match "99-99-9999 99:99:99"

Comment: I'm not a fan of validating the actual value of the data in the regexp; I'd much rather leave that to whatever comes after. I think of regular expressions like this one to simply be validation of format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!-- (?<month>\d\d)-(?<day>\d\d)-(?<year>\d{4})(?: \d\d:\d\d:\d\d(?: [aApP][mM]?)?)? -->
```

Is as simple as I can think of.  Note that this regex isn't exactly the same, since in the original the timestamp colons were all optional, meaning it would match 01:0203 or 0102:03:, etc.  I think my version may be more correct.

Basically I removed all the noncapturing groups and quantifiers I could, which when they are merely doubling a digit make it less readable, as opposed to more.  I also removed the greediness modifier on the quantifiers, since they will always match exactly 2 or 4 or whatever whether it's greedy or not.

And of course, this will match invalid dates, such as 13-32-0000.  To fix that, you will have to decide whether a complex yet correct solution is more desirable than a simple, more understandable one.  Basically, it depends on your confidence in the text you will be running this over.  If there are likely to be false positives that you want to filter out, go for a more correct solution, even if it is slightly less readable.

Comment: Ok thanks, I see what you did there. I am going to attempt to modify this pattern to accept valid date values as annakata pointed out under the OP comments.

Comment: Won't both yours and the original also only match on ---> (3 dashes), rather than --> (2 dashes) as most of the original examples contained?

Comment: @Twistol - oops, I forgot the third dash. That was a type ;(

Comment: @Twisol: Ooops. Didn't notice that when I copy-pasta'd!  I changed it to assume it was a typo in the original regex, and it should be two dashes.

Comment: On your "this will match invalid dates" bit of the answer, I think of regular expressions like this one to be better suited to simple validation of *format*, leaving the actual data validation to be done afterwards. It (a) makes for clearer regular expressions, and (b) is very useful where the "valid data" domain might be dynamic or  complex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take...

```
(?<month>\d{2}?)-(?<day>\d{2}?)-(?<year>\d{4})(?:\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s?[aApP]?[mM]?)?
```

Can't seem to make it any shorter.

Comment: Be sure to note that this one will match more invalid data than the original, for example the time portion could be 01:02:03M, since both the whitespace and a/p characters are mutually exclusively optional to the m.

Answer (score 0):

Why use Regex for this at all, and not use the `Convert.ToDateTime()`, `DateTime.Parse()` or `DateTime.TryParse()` methods included in .NET?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx